# I can not create a simple vbscript string

Tags: vbscript

I faced this problem many times and I'm looking for the causing reason.

```
sql="update setting set hashcode='"&hashcode&"'"
```

Error:

> sql="update setting set hashcode='"&hashcode&"'"
>
> ----------------------------------------------^
>
> Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0401'
>
> Expected end of statement

Please note that Changing the initial value of **hashcode** is not effective.

But this works fine

```
sql="update setting set anotherword='"&anotherword&"'"
```

Do you have any idea why renaming the parameter solves the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need whitespace surrounding the `&` character to prevent ambiguity.

`&ha` is seen as a numeric (hexadecimal) value, and it is illegal to directly follow a string, which is why an end of statement is expected. (`&h` denotes the start of a hexadecimal number in vbscript, and `a` is a valid hex digit.)

So your code should be:

```
sql = "update setting set hashcode = '" & hashcode & "'"
```

---

Side note: to prevent SQL injection (depending where the value inside your `hashcode` variable came from), you may want to use `replace(hashcode, "'", "''")`

Comment: OMG! what does "ha" really means? hexadecimal?

Comment: `&h` indicates a hexadecimal number. `&ha` is the hexadecimal number `A` (`0xA`).